# Passing structs by value with cffi-libffi?

Tags: c, opencv, common-lisp, libffi, cffi

I'm under the impression that CFFI cant pass structs by value,  but the CFFI documentation says:

> To pass or return a structure by value to a function, load the cffi-libffi system and specify the structure as `(:struct structure-name)`. To pass or return the pointer, you can use either `:pointer` or `(:pointer (:struct structure-name))`.

I'm re-wrapping the cl-opencv function `get-size`,  which is a wrapper for this opencv function:

```c
CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
```

and since I don't think CFFI had the ability to pass structs by value with the cffi-libffi system  when the author of cl-opencv wrote the library, so he had to use all of the following code to wrap `cvGetSize`:

```lisp
 (defmacro make-structure-serializers (struct slot1 slot2)
  "Create a serialization and deserialization function for the
structure STRUCT with integer slots SLOT1 and SLOT2. These functions
will pack and unpack the structure into an INT64."
  (let ((pack-fn (intern (concatenate 'string (string struct) 
                       (string '->int64))))
    (slot1-fn (intern (concatenate 'string (string struct) "-" 
                        (string slot1))))
    (slot2-fn (intern (concatenate 'string (string struct) "-" 
                        (string slot2))))
    (unpack-fn (intern (concatenate 'string (string 'int64->) 
                    (string struct))))
    (make-fn (intern (concatenate 'string (string 'make-) 
                       (string struct)))))
     `(progn
        (defun ,pack-fn (s)
     (+ (,slot1-fn s) (ash (,slot2-fn s) 32)))
        (defun ,unpack-fn (n)
     (,make-fn ,slot1 (logand n #x00000000ffffffff)
            ,slot2 (ash n -32))))))


;; CvSize - Input = (defparameter a (make-size :width 640 :height 480)) Output = #S(SIZE :WIDTH 640 :HEIGHT 480) for 
;; following the two.
(defstruct size (width 0) (height 0))
(make-structure-serializers :size :width :height)

;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) :int64
  (arr cv-array))

(defun get-size (arr)
  "Get the dimensions of the OpenCV array ARR. Return a size struct with the
dimensions."
  (let ((nsize (%get-size arr)))
     (int64->size nsize)))
```

Given the CFFI documentation quoted above, how would I pass this `cvGetSize` struct `CvSize` by value?

I intend to update the [cl-opencv](https://github.com/ryepup/cl-opencv) package, and I would like to know where and how in the cl-opencv package I would "load the cffi-libffi system" as per the CFFI  documentation, and where to "specify the structure as `(:struct structure-name)`" and "use either :pointer or (:pointer (:struct structure-name))" "to pass or return the pointer."

I could use detailed instructions on how to do that using the above `cvGetSize` wrapper:

```lisp
;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) :int64
  (arr cv-array))

(defun get-size (arr)
  "Get the dimensions of the OpenCV array ARR. Return a size struct with the
dimensions."
  (let ((nsize (%get-size arr)))
     (int64->size nsize)))
```

Edit for @Rörd

I appreciate your consice response

I get the same error either way...but for testing purposes lets say i load cffi-libffi
into my current session like this(with output)

```
CL-OPENCV> (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :cffi-libffi) 
#<ASDF:LOAD-OP NIL {10076CCF13}>
NIL
```

it loads so i run just the defcfun and the defcstruct you provided
like this (with output):

```
 CL-OPENCV> (cffi:defcstruct cv-size
           (width :int)
           (height :int))

  (:STRUCT CV-SIZE)
  CL-OPENCV> 
  (defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) (:struct cv-size)
    (arr cv-array))
  ; in: DEFCFUN ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE)
  ;     ("cvGetSize" CL-OPENCV::%GET-SIZE)
  ; 
  ; caught ERROR:
  ;   illegal function call
  ; 
  ; compilation unit finished
  ;   caught 1 ERROR condition

  Execution of a form compiled with errors.
  Form:
    ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE)
  Compile-time error:
    illegal function call
     [Condition of type SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR]

  Restarts:
   0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
   1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
   2: [ABORT] Abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1007BA8063}>)

      Backtrace:
             0: ((LAMBDA ()))
                 [No Locals]
             1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
                 Locals:
                   SB-DEBUG::ARG-0 = ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE)
                   SB-DEBUG::ARG-1 = #<NULL-LEXENV>
             2: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (DEFCFUN ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE) (:STRUCT CV-SIZE) (ARR CV-ARRAY)) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
                 Locals:
                   SB-DEBUG::ARG-0 = (DEFCFUN ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE) (:STRUCT CV-SIZE) (ARR CV-ARRAY))
                   SB-DEBUG::ARG-1 = #<NULL-LEXENV>
             3: (EVAL (DEFCFUN ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE) (:STRUCT CV-SIZE) (ARR CV-ARRAY)))
                 Locals:
```

I know libffi is installed correctly because with gsll loaded (which uses cffi-libffi)
i run the gsll tests and they all pass shown here(with output)

```
(ql:quickload "lisp-unit")
  (in-package :gsl)
  (lisp-unit:run-tests)
To load "lisp-unit":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    lisp-unit
     Loading "lisp-unit"
..................................
Unit Test Summary
 | 4023 assertions total
 | 4022 passed
 | 1 failed
 | 0 execution errors
 | 0 missing tests

#<TEST-RESULTS-DB Total(4023) Passed(4022) Failed(1) Errors(0)>
```

It doesnt seem to be calling the defcfun with the (:struct cv-size)
as the issue because when i call it like

```
(defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) cv-size
  (arr cv-array))
```

i get same error

```
Execution of a form compiled with errors.
Form:
  ("cvGetSize" %GET-SIZE)
Compile-time error:
```

I can run my ipl-image struct though like this

```
CL-OPENCV> ;; ;(cffi:foreign-type-size '(:struct ipl-image)) = 144
(cffi:defcstruct ipl-image
(n-size :int)
(id :int)
(n-channels :int)
(alpha-channel :int)
(depth :int)
(color-model :pointer) 
(channel-seq :pointer) 
(data-order :int)
(origin :int)
(align :int)
(width :int)
(height :int)
(roi :pointer)
(mask-roi :pointer)
(image-id :pointer)
(tile-info :pointer)
(image-size :int)
(image-data :string)
(width-step :int)
(border-mode :pointer)
(border-const :pointer)
(image-data-origin :string))

   output>(:STRUCT IPL-IMAGE)
```

and my create-image wrapper now with cffi-libffi loaded and your (:struct ipl-image) on 
it runs fine it though ...shown with output

```
;; IplImage* cvCreateImage(CvSize size, int depth, int channels)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvCreateImage" %create-image) (:struct ipl-image)
  (size :int64)
  (depth :int)
  (channels :int))

(defun create-image (size depth channels)
  "Create an image with dimensions given by SIZE, DEPTH bits per
channel, and CHANNELS number of channels."
 (let ((nsize (size->int64 size)))
    (%create-image nsize depth channels)))
```

CREATE-IMAGE

but when i run

```
(defparameter img-size (make-size :width 640 :height 480))

(defparameter img (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 1))
```

create an image at repl nothing happens the repl just hangs...

but when i run the create image wrapper with ipl-image instead of (:struct ipl-image)

i can run the :

```
 (defparameter img-size (make-size :width 640 :height 480))

 (defparameter img (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 1))
```

fine then run this to access the struct values (with output)

```
 (cffi:with-foreign-slots ((
  n-size
  id
  n-channels
  alpha-channel
  depth
  color-model
  channel-seq
  data-order
  origin
  align
  width
  height
  roi
  mask-roi
  image-id
  tile-info
  image-size
  image-data
  width-step
  border-mode
  border-const
  image-data-origin) img (:struct ipl-image))
            (cffi:mem-ref img :char )
            (format t "n-size ~a ~%" n-size)
            (format t "id ~a ~%" id)
            (format t "n-channels ~a ~%" n-channels)
            (format t "alpha-channel ~a ~%" alpha-channel)
            (format t "depth ~a ~%" depth)
            (format t "color-model ~a ~%" color-model)
            (format t "channel-seq ~a ~%" channel-seq)
            (format t "data-order ~a ~%" data-order)
            (format t "origin ~a ~%" origin)
            (format t "align ~a ~%" align)
            (format t "width ~a ~%" width)
            (format t "height ~a ~%" height)
            (format t "roi ~a ~%" roi)
            (format t "mask-roi ~a ~%" mask-roi)
            (format t "image-id ~a ~%" image-id)
            (format t "tile-info ~a ~%" tile-info)
            (format t "image-size ~a ~%" image-size)
            (format t "image-data ~a ~%" image-data)
            (format t "width-step ~a ~%" width-step)
            (format t "border-mode ~a ~%" border-mode)
            (format t "border-const ~a ~%" border-const)
            (format t "image-data-origin ~a ~%" image-data-origin))
  output>
  n-size 144 
  id 0 
  n-channels 1 
  alpha-channel 0 
  depth 8 
  color-model #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X59415247) 
  channel-seq #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X400000000) 
  data-order 640 
  origin 480 
  align 0 
  width 0 
  height 0 
  roi #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000) 
  mask-roi #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000) 
  image-id #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0004B000) 
  tile-info #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFF7F04020) 
  image-size 640 
  image-data NIL 
  width-step 0 
  border-mode #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000) 
  border-const #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000) 
  image-data-origin
```

but im not getting a struct by value i get

```
 color-model #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X59415247)
```

which when i cout that value img->colorModel in c with this

```
IplImage* img=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cout << "colorModel = " << endl << " " << img->colorModel << endl << endl;

output> colorModel = 
 RGB
```

so any help would be much appreciated

ok 1 more edit:

I tried it again and it worked here is my output

```
  CL-OPENCV> (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :cffi-libffi)
  #<ASDF:LOAD-OP NIL {1006D7B1F3}>
  NIL
  CL-OPENCV> 
  ;; ;(cffi:foreign-type-size '(:struct cv-size)) = 8
  (cffi:defcstruct cv-size
      (width :int)
      (height :int))

  ;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
  (cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) (:struct cv-size)
    (arr cv-array))

  STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV::%GET-SIZE in DEFUN
  %GET-SIZE
  CL-OPENCV> 

   (defparameter img-size (make-size :width 640 :height 480))

  (defparameter img (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 1))

  IMG
  CL-OPENCV> 

   (defparameter size (%get-size img))
  SIZE
  CL-OPENCV> size
  (HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)
  CL-OPENCV>
```

dont know what i did wrong first time but...if you can check my results and verify i have just passed a struct by value  i would be forever grateful

thanks Rord

ok another edit if your still interested in helping me debug Rord

if getting error:

```
  The value (HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)
   is not of type
   SB-SYS:SYSTEM-AREA-POINTER.
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

and here is the history that caused it(this happened directly after i posted the prev. edit so my emacs has all the prev. edits code loaded still):

```
   CL-OPENCV> (defun get-size (arr)
    "Get the dimensions of the OpenCV array ARR. Return a size struct with the
  dimensions."
    (cffi:with-foreign-slots ((width height) (%get-size arr) (:struct cv-size))
      (make-size :width width :height height)))
  STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV:GET-SIZE in DEFUN
  GET-SIZE
  CL-OPENCV> 

   (defparameter img-size (make-size :width 640 :height 480))

  (defparameter img (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 1))

  IMG
  CL-OPENCV> 

   (defparameter size (get-size img))


  The value (HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)
   is not of type
   SB-SYS:SYSTEM-AREA-POINTER.
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

I get that because the:

```
(defparameter size (get-size img))
```

accesses your defun...i traced it so when i just run - shown with output:

```
CL-OPENCV> 
;; ;(cffi:foreign-type-size '(:struct cv-size)) = 8
(cffi:defcstruct cv-size
        (width :int)
        (height :int))

;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
 (cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) (:struct cv-size)
  (arr cv-array))

STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV::%GET-SIZE in DEFUN
%GET-SIZE
CL-OPENCV> (defparameter capture (create-camera-capture 0))
CAPTURE
CL-OPENCV> (defparameter frame (query-frame capture))
FRAME
CL-OPENCV> 

(defparameter size (%get-size frame))
SIZE
CL-OPENCV> size
(HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)
CL-OPENCV> (cffi:with-foreign-slots ((width height) size (:struct cv-size))
        (list width height ))
```

i get error:

```
The value (HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)
  is not of type
    SB-SYS:SYSTEM-AREA-POINTER.
     [Condition of type
```

I think its because the out put of your defcfun is just a list and with-foreign-slots needs a pointer

i ran this:

```
(HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)
CL-OPENCV> (first size)
HEIGHT
```

to verify and its just a list

btw i used these functions for test

```
(defparameter capture (create-camera-capture 0))

(defparameter frame (query-frame capture))
```

because the have a more pure output...create-image uses the hackery of the get-size i oroginally posted at the top of this ?

I'd like to use create-image and get-size w/o all the hackery  and just use the structs for returns so i could stop using the make-size and make it more pure....so any advice on that would be gold...here is how i would like to have create-image...I just gotta get it to accept the output from your(Rord's) defcfun...I'm now tring to turn your defcfun output((HEIGHT 480 WIDTH 640)) to a pointer...so it will just run in this

```
;; IplImage* cvCreateImage(CvSize size, int depth, int channels)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvCreateImage" %create-image) ipl-image
  (size cv-size)
  (depth :int)
  (channels :int))
```

or is the whole make-size thing going to be a neccessity...

also fyi i changed the defun you added to

```
(defun get-size (arr)
  "Get the dimensions of the OpenCV array ARR. Return a size struct with the
dimensions."
  (setf arr (%get-size arr))
  (make-size :width (cadddr arr) :height (cadr arr)))
```

and it works now...still curios if i messed something up and if your defun would have been better

EDIT!!!!I GOT IT ALL FIGURED OUT!!!!!

```
here is the repl output :

; SLIME 2012-05-25
CL-OPENCV> ;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" get-size) (:pointer (:struct cv-size))
  (arr cv-array))
STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV:GET-SIZE in DEFUN
GET-SIZE
CL-OPENCV> ;; IplImage* cvCreateImage(CvSize size, int depth, int channels)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvCreateImage" create-image) (:pointer (:struct ipl-image))
   (size (:pointer (:struct ipl-image)))
  (depth :int)
  (channels :int))


STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV:CREATE-IMAGE in DEFUN
CREATE-IMAGE
CL-OPENCV> (defun detect-red-objects (&optional (camera-index 0))
   "Uses IN-RANGE-SCALAR to detect red objects"
  (with-capture (capture (create-camera-capture camera-index))
    (let ((window-name-1 "Video")
          (window-name-2 "Ball"))
           (named-window window-name-1)
           (named-window window-name-2)
           (move-window window-name-1 290 225)
           (move-window window-name-2 940 225)
      (do* ((frame (query-frame capture) (query-frame capture))
             (img (clone-image frame))
              (frame (clone-image img))
              (img-size (get-size frame))          
              (img-hsv (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 3))
              (img-hsv-size (get-size img-hsv))
            (img-thresh (create-image img-hsv-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 1))
             (scalar-1 (make-cv-scalar 170.0 160.0 60.0))
             (scalar-2 (make-cv-scalar 180.0 256.0 256.0)))
         ((plusp (wait-key *millis-per-frame*)) nil)
             (smooth frame frame +gaussian+ 3 3)
             (cvt-color frame img-hsv +bgr2hsv+)
             (in-range-s img-hsv scalar-1 scalar-2 img-thresh)
             (smooth img-thresh img-thresh +gaussian+ 3 3)
             (show-image window-name-1 frame)
             (show-image window-name-2 img-thresh))
          (destroy-all-windows))))
DETECT-RED-OBJECTS

(the function detect-red-objects runs btw!...
```

EDIT!!!!I GOT IT ALL FIGURED OUT!!!!!...Part....II - Even Better!

```
I messed up the struct on create-image the first time but it still ran...weird...but it runs when put the create-image struct back to cv-size....so no prob there...here is revised repl output


; SLIME 2012-05-25
CL-OPENCV> ;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" get-size) (:pointer (:struct cv-size))
  (arr cv-array))
STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV:GET-SIZE in DEFUN
GET-SIZE
CL-OPENCV> ;; IplImage* cvCreateImage(CvSize size, int depth, int channels)
(cffi:defcfun ("cvCreateImage" create-image) (:pointer (:struct ipl-image))
  (size (:pointer (:struct cv-size)))
  (depth :int)
  (channels :int))

STYLE-WARNING: redefining CL-OPENCV:CREATE-IMAGE in DEFUN
CREATE-IMAGE
CL-OPENCV> (defun detect-red-objects (&optional (camera-index 0))
   "Uses IN-RANGE-SCALAR to detect red objects"
  (with-capture (capture (create-camera-capture camera-index))
    (let ((window-name-1 "Video")
          (window-name-2 "Ball"))
           (named-window window-name-1)
           (named-window window-name-2)
           (move-window window-name-1 290 225)
           (move-window window-name-2 940 225)
      (do* ((frame (query-frame capture) (query-frame capture))
             (img (clone-image frame))
              (frame (clone-image img))
              (img-size (get-size frame))           
              (img-hsv (create-image img-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 3))
              (img-hsv-size (get-size img-hsv))
            (img-thresh (create-image img-hsv-size +ipl-depth-8u+ 1))
             (scalar-1 (make-cv-scalar 170.0 160.0 60.0))
             (scalar-2 (make-cv-scalar 180.0 256.0 256.0)))
         ((plusp (wait-key *millis-per-frame*)) nil)
             (smooth frame frame +gaussian+ 3 3)
             (cvt-color frame img-hsv +bgr2hsv+)
             (in-range-s img-hsv scalar-1 scalar-2 img-thresh)
             (smooth img-thresh img-thresh +gaussian+ 3 3)
             (show-image window-name-1 frame)
             (show-image window-name-2 img-thresh)) 
          (destroy-all-windows))))
DETECT-RED-OBJECTS
```

@Liam Edit

ok I tried your translate-from-foreign method and it did work
i have these defined in my structs.lisp file

```
(cffi:defcstruct (cv-size :class cv-size-type)
  (width :int)
  (height :int))

(defmethod cffi:translate-from-foreign (p (type cv-size-type))
  (let ((plist (call-next-method)))
    (make-size :width (getf plist 'width)
               :height (getf plist 'height))))
```

and get-size and create-image are defined like this

```
;; CvSize cvGetSize(const CvArr* arr)
 (cffi:defcfun ("cvGetSize" get-size) (:struct cv-size)
   (arr cv-arr))

 ;; IplImage* cvCreateImage(CvSize size, int depth, int channels)
 (cffi:defcfun ("cvCreateImage" %create-image) ipl-image
   (size :int64)
   (depth :int)
   (channels :int))

 (defun create-image (size depth channels)
   "Create an image with dimensions given by SIZE, DEPTH bits per
 channel, and CHANNELS number of channels."
   (let ((nsize (size->int64 size)))
     (%create-image nsize depth channels)))
```

here is the definition of size->int64

```
  (DEFUN SIZE->INT64 (S) (+ (SIZE-WIDTH S) (ASH (SIZE-HEIGHT S) 32)))
```

but i love the idea of the translate-foreign defmethod's

so i was wondering if you can show my how to make the translate-into-foreign version of the below from method this would really make my library sing...I'm aiming to make a complete cffi wrapper for opencv as good as gsll is to gsl so this would really help that happen quicker....Thanks again for your help on all this so far

```
(defmethod cffi:translate-from-foreign (p (type cv-size-type))
  (let ((plist (call-next-method)))
    (make-size :width (getf plist 'width)
               :height (getf plist 'height))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To "load the cffi-libffi system", you need to specify it as dependency in the library's `.asd` file. (Note: cffi-libffi needs the C library libffi to be installed on your system.)

To be able to use `(:struct structure-name)`, you need to first define the structure with `cffi:defcstruct`, like this (I will assume here that `cffi:defcstruct`, `cffi:defcfun`, and `cffi:with-foreign-slots` are imported in the current package):

```
(defcstruct cv-size
  (width :int)
  (height :int))
```

You can then use `(:struct cv-size)` in the `defcfun` like this:

```
(defcfun ("cvGetSize" %get-size) (:struct cv-size)
  (arr cv-array))
```

**EDIT**: Fixed `get-size` for passed-by-value structs.

And finally define `get-size` like this:

```
(defun get-size (arr)
  "Get the dimensions of the OpenCV array ARR. Return a size struct with the
dimensions."
  (let ((%size (%get-size arr)))
    (make-size :width (getf %size 'width)
               :height (getf %size 'height))))
```

**EDIT 2**:

If I understand Liam's answer correctly, this is how to write a `translate-from-foreign` method so that it creates the struct directly, without creating the intermediate plist:

```
(defmethod cffi:translate-from-foreign (p (type cv-size-type))
  (with-foreign-slots ((width height) p (:struct cv-size))
    (make-size :width width :height height)))
```

Comment: @user2735131: The first error message you're getting (on the `defcfun` form) is probably because you don't have the symbols from `cffi` imported into your current package. Try that again with `cffi:defcfun` instead of just `defcfun`. (SBCL doesn't know `defcfun` is supposed to be a macro and therefore tries to evaluate the arguments `("cvGetSize" %get-size)` as a function call.)

Comment: thanks @Rörd I had just unkowingly figured that out before i saw your response but i didnt know why it worked this time ....your very timely response just know showed me why....THANK YOU VERY MUCH!...ill give credit to you on my release of a COMPLETE cl-opencv as the guy who helped me figure out structs by value...so if you wanna send me your email or something (my email link is on S.O.) I'll make sure its added with your credit...thanks again! your a kind man =)

Comment: I got a new error on the... defun i did some testing though detailed in the latest edits to my ?

Comment: @user2735131: Sorry, I didn't actually have a C library that returns structs by value available for testing and therefore overlooked that `with-foreign-slots` only works on pointers. I have edited my answer so it contains a fixed version of `get-size` now. The problem with your own fixed version is that it hard-codes the position of the values within the list, but these positions are not guaranteed. A list where the elements are alternating between keys and values is called a *property list* or *plist*, and the right way to access it is the function `getf` which my version uses.

Comment: Thanks man....that was cool helping me out like that...thanks for staying with me...ever done any tutoring btw

Comment: @user2735131: I once did a similar project (updating an older package of cffi bindings to a C library). Here's the repository: https://github.com/roerd/cl-rsvg2. You can find my name and email in the files there. I never did tutoring as a job, so far, though I've frequently been helping lab partners or answering questions online, on SO and other places.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info....You are very kind....fyi I added the defun and defcfun to my package....it is beautiful...my first fsbv

Comment: Small correction: you need to load not just the libffi library, but the headers. Oftentimes, an operating system will install the library but not the headers. Debian/Ubuntu for example have a package libffi-dev which needs to be installed.

Comment: @Liam ....Thanks Mr. Healy........U are the author or of my 2 favorite packages....cffi-libffi and gsll (cffi?)...I love em both....DEARLY.....Any man who loves Math that much can't be bad!!!

Btw,  I got my struct issue figured out and got rid of the need for the make-size completley.....as detailed in my last edit!

 A very good day to you!,Sir.

Comment: @Liam can u look at my latest edit with your name on it...Im hoping to get you to help me write the translate into foreign  method....the other one worked like a charm....Thanks again for that..

Comment: @Liam this question is kinda full....if you would like to see my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133763/how-do-i-write-a-comparable-cffitranslate-into-foreign-defmethod-for-this-cffi it would be easier 2 navigate than this one and i ask the same thing but more concise....=)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define both `%get-size` and `get-size`. Instead, you could define

```
(defcstruct (cv-size :class cv-size-type)
  (width :int)
  (height :int))

(defmethod cffi:translate-from-foreign (p (type cv-size-type))
  (let ((plist (call-next-method)))
    (make-size :width (getf plist 'width)
               :height (getf plist 'height))))
```

and then define the function `get-size` directly with the `defcfun`.

The benefit of doing it this way is anytime you have a function that returns a cv-size, it will automatically get translated. And, if you have foreign functions to which you want to pass a cv-size, define the appropriate method for cffi:translate-into-foreign-memory. You will also get the translation automatically if you use mem-aref on a pointer to the structure. Or, if you call cffi:convert-from-foreign.

In this example, I have used the default plist translation method; you can if you wish directly access the slots without calling (call-next-method).

(BTW, the reason you were under the impression that CFFI could not pass structures by value was that it couldn't until recently; cffi-libffi was introduced with release 0.11.0.)

Comment: @Liam....I just noticed your answer....Thanks by the way(its great when an author of a library cares so much about its users to answer their Questions's like this) Pls tell me what do you think about my latest edits....are they better or worse than your idea and if so why?...They do work, their short and minimal and they prove the perfection of cffi....I really like that...i was always hoping cffi was perfect....now i'm even more sure it is...

Comment: Thanks for joining this discussion. The reason why I kept the conversion to a Lisp struct around in my answer is that I consider them to be more convenient to access from Lisp. Of course, if you only want to pass around these values from one C function to another, that doesn't matter and it's also more efficient to just use the plists directly.

Comment: @Rörd Why do you fell they are more "convenient to access from Lisp"  ....If possible could you give me an example of why the make-size is better than the styles detailed in my last two "I got it all figured out" edits....

Comment: @user2735131: Whether it's "better" depends upon the way it's supposed to be used. I consider Lisp structs more convenient because of all the functions `defstruct` gives me automatically: a constructor function (e.g. `make-size`) to create these values in Lisp, accessor functions, and a type predicate. Of course, you could also define these kinds of functions yourself for the plist resp. write a macro that will create these functions. `defstruct` is just a nice standard way to achieve that, but as a drawback it means converting the same C value twice, to two different representations.

Comment: @Rörd ....Very well Said....Do you think there would be some sort of benchmark difference betweeen defcstruct and defstruct over lets say a million iterations

Comment: @user2735131: There's definitely going to be a performance difference, but its extent would depend upon which operation(s) exactly were measured. Converting a value a million times from C to Lisp and back would be a very significant difference, because in that case, using the `defstruct` type would almost double the amount of memory that would need to be allocated (because the plists would still be needed, but only as intermediate format), and allocating would be basically all you do. On the other hand, the more you would do with these values in Lisp, the smaller that difference would become.

Comment: @user2735131: Based on Liam's suggestion, I have now added a `translate-from-foreign` example to my answer that doesn't create an intermediate plist. That should give you the best of both worlds in terms of efficiency and convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `:class xxx` to `cffi:defcstruct` then `(cffi:defmethod translate-into-foreign-memory (object (type xxx) pointer) yyyy)`, it will pass structure by value to a foreign function automatically!! Amazing!!

And `(cffi:defmethod translate-from-foreign (pointer (type xxx)) zzzz)` will convert the returned structure data into lisp data.

More information please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39942257/2765530) also by me^_^